# Is this use of union well defined?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, unions

Consider the following code:

```
union
{
    PrStatus_X86_64 prstat64;
    PrStatus_X86    prstat32;
} prstat;

iovec prstat_iov = {&prstat, sizeof prstat};

if(ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGSET, tid, NT_PRSTATUS, &prstat_iov) != -1)
{
    if(prstat_iov.iov_len==sizeof prstat.prstat64)
        use(prstat.prstat64);
    else if(prstat_iov.iov_len==sizeof prstat.prstat32)
        use(prstat.prstat32);
}
```

Here, depending on what the `ptrace` call returns as the resulting `prstat_iov.iov_len`, `prstat` should be interpreted either as one structure, or as another one.

As is well known, in C++ unions can't be used as freely as in C, namely, reading an inactive member of a union results in undefined behavior. But can we consider that the `ptrace` call in the above code will actually act as "writing to the correct member" of the union, according to the C++ Standard, so that the above code would have well-defined behavior?

Comment: Does ptrace write data into proper union member? If it does, all is well. If it doesn't, this is still undefined behavior.

Comment: @SergeyA the problem is `ptrace` can be implemented in completely another language — be it C or assembly or something exotic. Would it count if the code is "intended to" write to the correct union member but doesn't expressly do this in C++ syntax?

Comment: interoperations between C++ code and *exotic* code are not defined anyways. If you want this union to be interoperable, it has to be inside `extern "C"`. I will post a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

In essence, the question can be rephrased in a shorter form:

```
union A {
   int x;
   int y;
};

A a;
my_non_cpp_function(&a);
```

Now the question becomes, since it is absolutely unknown to C++ compiler how would non-cpp function access the members of the union, how do we define which member of the union is active? (remember, C explicitly allows accessing inactive member)!

Answer is simple. Since interface between C++ and non-C++ constructs is not defined anyways, the properl solution is to declare union inside `extern "C"` block. This would ensure C linkage for the union, and, in turn, make it defined to access inactive member.

Comment: Your last sentence seems to imply that it's enough to declare a union to have C linkage to get the right to use it arbitrarily with the C rules for a union (i.e. accessing inactive member)... or do I misunderstand anything?

Comment: @Ruslan, this is exactly what I mean.

Comment: So the code like `extern "C" { union A{float x;int y;}a;} /*...*/ a.x=5;f(a.y);` would be well-defined (up to trap representations)?

Comment: @Ruslan, yes. It will follow C rules, which allow inactive union member access.

Comment: Dunno. This must have some critical look from others for several days. Your statement leaves me in a big doubt: it seems very strange that just specifying a different linkage drastically changes the rules of the language about usage of a data structure. If you can back up this with a quote, I'll be more than happy to upvote and accept immediately.

Comment: I've tried looking for confirmation of your assertion in the C++ standard, but AFAICT, linkage there only defines how identifiers refer to one another in different translation units. I've found nothing which would say about different rules of usage of their types. So it seems your assertion is wrong.

Comment: I'm glad you're so self-confident, but maybe you could provide some proof/evidence of your rightness?

Comment: @Ruslan, 7.5 / 1. `Some of the properties associated with an entity with language linkage are specific to each implementation and are not described here. For example....`. This is what I am talking about.

Comment: OK, that's already something, thanks. Now this still doesn't guarantee that any particular properties of these entities will be exactly as in C. Also notes are informative, not normative in C++ standard.

Comment: @Ruslan, judging by the name, you should be familiar with Ostap Bender? Full guarantee can only be obtained through insurance policy. However, you can be very much sure this is happening. Otherwise, no C++ code could use endless C unions defined in thousands of low-level system API.

Comment: Well, this might be a good argument, but my question was explicitly marked with [tag:language-lawyer] tag from the beginning. I'm interested in correctness of the code according to the standard, otherwise I'd be satisfied with what most compilers allow me to do (with their documentation explicitly mentioning this).

Comment: C++ doesn't cover questions of correctness of C code. However, I am tired of this fruitless discussion, so you can choose whatever approach fits you best.